# Error #7062 in FORTRAN, can't find the characteristic of dummy argument of associated procedure

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I'm using a function called a DDE_SOLVER and passing 2nd argument known as DDES. The DDES arguments contain more arguments 'T, Y, Z, DY' The T argument successfully complies but can't get the error in Y, Z, and DY.

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 with the latest Intel Parallel Studio XE 2019. It worked on Windows XP because of being the old version but does not work on Windows 10 according to my colleague.

```
MODULE define_DDEs

   IMPLICIT NONE

   INTEGER, PARAMETER :: NEQN=2,NLAGS=2
   INTEGER :: u, tou
   DOUBLE PRECISION :: x, tou1,tou2, del1, del2

CONTAINS

   SUBROUTINE DDES(T,Y,Z,DY)

     DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(IN) :: T
     DOUBLE PRECISION,  INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(2):: Y
     DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(2), INTENT(INOUT) :: DY
     DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(2,2), INTENT(IN) :: Z
     !INTENT(OUT) :: DY
     DOUBLE PRECISION ::a=4.5,q=4,p=2,r=3.8

         ! a=0.04,q=.06,p=.5,r=0.05
        ! a = 0.11 ,  b =0.2, d0=1, s=1 , d=0.5, d1=2.0, a1=0.9
           !t1=1.6a = 0.11D0 ,  b = 0.2D0, d0=1, s=1 , a1 = 0.9 , d1 = 2.0D0, d = 0.5D0 


!! Change the file name first
!  for delay   Y(t-tou_2)=Z(2,2) 
DY(1) = Y(1)*(1-Z(1,1))-(Y(2)*Y(1))/(Y(1)+a)        !(1+a1*SIN(Y(3)))*
DY(2) = Y(2)*p-(q*Z(2,2)*Y(2))/(r+Z(1,2))
!DY(3) = d1  

    RETURN
  END SUBROUTINE DDES

  END MODULE define_DDEs




  !IN MAIN FUNCTION
  SOL = DDE_SOLVER(NVAR,DDES,(/5D0,tou2/),HISTORY,TSPAN)
```

The error is as follows:

```
 error #7062: The characteristics of dummy argument 2 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 2 of the dummy procedure.
 error #7063: The characteristics of dummy argument 3 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 3 of the dummy procedure.
 error #7064: The characteristics of dummy argument 4 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 4 of the dummy procedure.
```

I can't understand the characteristic of dummy variables in the associated procedure. It'd be really helpful if someone could fix the error.

Comment: Show us a [mcve].  What's the devinition of `dde_solver` ?  And, while you're editing your question tidy up the indentation and delete the commented out lines which are purely a distraction.

Comment: You need to show us the declaration of DDE_SOLVER. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Older compilers didn't check the arguments of passed procedures as carefully. INTENT must match as well.

Comment: FYI: I have an updated version of dde_solver at https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/dde_solver.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler message tells you that the type of the dummy and actual variable differ. in the subroutine for example the variable y is declared as a double precision array real valued array of dimension 2.
Now check in the rotine that calles ddes for the declaration of the corresponding variable. 
What you show at the bottom of your incomplete snippet is a function call to a function dde_solver, which is not in reference to the subroutine ddes.
so, loo for something like

```
call ddes
```

and present a complete compilable code.